# Vue.js - Use terminal while app is running with npm run serve

Tags: vue.js, npm, visual-studio-code, terminal, vue-cli

I've created a Vue.js project and after typing `npm run serve` command in a terminal (win10 - terminal from vsc), I've got a problem. I just cannot type anything in the terminal afterwards. Any guesses what I am doing wrong?

```
DONE  Compiled successfully in 1924ms                  11:12:24

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8081/
  - Network: http://192.168.0.54:8081/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, run npm run build.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal, you haven't done anything wrong.  If you need to continue using the terminal, you can split the terminal window

```
VSCode Menubar > "Terminal" > "Split Terminal"
```

-or-

```
Right-click Terminal window > "Split"
```

-or- (windows)

```
CTRL + SHIFT + 5
```